# Compile multiple .tex files

Tags: macros, pdftex

I have multiple .tex files (eg 1.tex, 2.tex, 3.tex etc) that don't contain a preamble or \begin{document} \end{document} commands.

The contents of each .tex files follows the simple structure below.

```
Item 1.
This line contains information for item 1.
This line contains resources for item 1.
Item 2.
This line contains information for item 2.
This line contains resources for item 2.
Item 3.
This line contains information for item 3.
This line contains resources for item 3.
.
.
.
```

I would like to compile all those .tex files NOT as a single .tex file but as a multiple .tex file. Basically what I'm after is the pdf of each .tex file (1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf and so on).

What i've tried is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\input{1} % I need item 1 (all three lines), 2, 3 and so on to be wrapped around \begin{equation} \end{equation}
\input{2}% I need item 1, 2, 3 and so on to be wrapped around \begin{equation} \end{equation}
\input{3}% I need item 1, 2, 3 and so on to be wrapped around \begin{equation} \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The problem with the above code is:

1. It compiles it to ONE pdf.
2. I need all those items (all the three lines that belong to the item) to be wrapped around \begin{equation} \end{equation}
3. Compile those files into their own pdf.

I'm not sure if its doable within LaTeX or should I be looking at python to run this type of work flow.

Comment: Maybe using external programs to auto run that for you would be a good choice. Writing a (for example) python script wouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing a python script that aims to compile all the individual .tex file. I'm not sure if its possible to compile to pdf without having to open the .tex file.

Comment: Just like all command-line usage, for example calling `latexmk -pdfxe 1.tex`.

Comment: It is rather hard to understand the requirement or test answers as the supplied code does not match the description. Please fix the example to have some math and make it clearer where you want to insert `\begin{equation}` For example is `Item 2.` literal text to appear in the output or simply a marker to be replaced by `\end{equation}\begin{equation}` ? (although you should never have immediately adjacent  `equation` evironments)

Comment: If you are an AUCTeX user, you search for the regular expression "\\(\\input{[^}]+}\\)" and run TeX-command-region on the corresponding region. It's easy enough to create a keyboard function or macro to automate this for an entire document.